# GCE image import stuck at removing VMWare Tools

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vmware

I am trying to import a Windows 10 vmdk to GCE.  The image was created with VMWare with VMWare tools installed. However, it got stuck trying to remove VMWare tools, it will reboot harddrive 0 and repeat again. Does anyone know where I can find more information on this?

```
2020/03/30 08:34:37 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 20200129.00).
2020/03/30 08:34:37 GCEMetadataScripts: Found windows-startup-script-url in metadata.
2020/03/30 08:34:38 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Translate: Beginning translate PowerShell script.
2020/03/30 08:34:38 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url: Translate: Found VMWare Tools installed, removing...
2020/03/30 08:34:42 GCEMetadataScripts: windows-startup-script-url exit status 0
2020/03/30 08:34:42 GCEMetadataScripts: Finished running startup scripts.
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall VMWare tools before importing image to GCE as described in the [documentation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2010137)? Have you check documentation [Importing virtual disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks)?

Comment: Thanks for your response Serhii.  It is working without VMWare tools installed.  However, we are using this image for multiple environments and try to avoid having a different image for GCE.  I want to see if there is a way I can get more information on why it got stuck.

Comment: Please update your question with your steps you follow to import image to GCP from copying VMWare image with commands and outputs to make me able to analyze them. I'll update my answer if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve your issue:

1. Remove VMWare Tools manually by following [documentation](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2010137) before importing VM to GCE.
2. Use [Migrate for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine) (formerly Velostrata) that is able to make [Modifications for run-in-cloud on Windows VMs](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/concepts/planning-a-migration/vm-adaptations#modifications_for_run-in-cloud_on_windows_vms):

   > Before moving the Windows VM to Google Cloud, Velostrata shuts down
   >   the VM and takes a snapshot. Velostrata then modifies the networking
   >   and storage drivers to allow the VM to boot in the cloud.
   >
   > - Install the NETKVM driver for Velostrata.
   > - Change network configuration.
   > - System tuning for iSCSI and MPIO access.
   > - Change license/edition.
   > - **Disable VMware tools**.
   > - Change page file location.
   > - Ensure hibernation is disabled.
   > - Change recovery options.
   > - Enable RDP.
   > - Deploy the Velostrata framework that allows you to run custom actions.

   [Migrate for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine) (formerly Velostrata) allows you to [Running a VM in Compute Engine or starting a migration](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/migrate-on-premises-to-gcp/running-and-migrating-vms#running_a_vm_in_or_starting_a_migration) or [Moving a VM back on-premises](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/vm-operations/running-a-vm-back-on-premises). More information about possible integration with VMware you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.9/how-to/migrate-on-premises-to-gcp/overview).